# How I can store variable like instance in model.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For example, I have this array:

```
   tags_array=['<code>','<span>','<div>', '<label>','<a>', '<br>', '<p>' '<b>','<i>', '<del>', '<strike>', '<u>', '<img>', '<video>', '<audio>', '<iframe>', '<object>', '<embed>', '<param>', '<blockquote>', '<mark>', '<cite>', '<small>', '<ul>', '<ol>', '<li>', '<hr>', '<dl>', '<dt>', '<dd>', '<sup>', '<sub>', '<big>', '<pre>', '<code>', '<figure>', '<figcaption>', '<strong>', '<em>', '<table>', '<tr>', '<td>', '<th>', '<tbody>', '<thead>', '<tfoot>', '<h1>', '<h2>', '<h3>', '<h4>', '<h5>','<h6>']
```

I don't want to define it in each model method where I use it, it seems not very smart copy-pasting.

And of course I don't want separate DB row for that.

How can I define it once, so it would be visible for each model method, like instance `initialize` method.

Like

```
class MyModel<ActiveRecord::Base

#...
@tags_array=['','',...]

def onemethod
@tags_array.split!
#...
end

def twomethod
@tags_array.capitalize!
#...
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define it as a module and mix it in.

```
module TagsArray

  tags_array=['','',...]

  def self.onemethod
  tags_array.split
  #...
  end

  def self.twomethod
  tags_array.capitalize
  #...
  end

end
```

Then you can just mix it in to your Models.

```
class MyModel<ActiveRecord::Base
  include TagsArray
end
```

Hope this helps.

Also you can drop the ! from the end of split and capitalize unless you want to alter the tags_array permanently each time you call the method.

Comment: Thanks. Please tell me where I can place Module file and I will approve

Comment: You can put them pretty much anywhere, but here's some tips http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013486/ruby-on-rails-where-should-i-store-modules