# How to create a common after_create callback for all models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Consider I have the models User, Account and Products. I want a common after_create callback for all these models say log_creation.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have a `GenericModule` and include this in any model you wish

```
module GenericModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_create :log_creation
  end

  def log_creation
    # perform logging
  end
end
```

And in the model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include GenericModule

  # ...other model code...
end
```

You can have this for all your models in which you need this behavior.

Comment: would the module be in the lib?

Comment: @PiKaY https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013486/ruby-on-rails-where-should-i-store-modules

Comment: @Kavincat Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the Ruby on Rails Guides on [ActiveRecord Callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0.2/active_record_callbacks.html#callback-classes):

Active Record makes it possible to create classes that encapsulate the callback methods, so it becomes very easy to reuse them.

Here's an example where we create a class with an after_destroy callback for a `PictureFile` model:

```
class PictureFileCallbacks
  def after_destroy(picture_file)
    if File.exists?(picture_file.filepath)
      File.delete(picture_file.filepath)
    end
  end
end
```

When declared inside a class, as above, the callback methods will receive the model object as a parameter. We can now use the callback class in the model:

```
class PictureFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_destroy PictureFileCallbacks.new
end
```